# Close Dialog Display Bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Whenever I open the close question dialog on my laptop's 13" display, the upper portion of the popup winds up on top of the "Questions Tags Users..." navigation bar, but due to an issue with the assigned `z-index` of the popup versus that of the navigation bar, the navigation bar trumps the dialog and bleeds through.

[image: Example of Error]

It appears that by setting the `z-index` on the `#close-question-popup` to a minimum value of 80, the dialog will then be the prominent element. Alternatively you could take the `z-index` of 80 off of the `#hmenus` element, although I don't know of the repercussions this may have on the site.

For reference, my I am running Google Chrome 23.0.1271.101 on a 13" MacBook Pro with OSX 10.7.5.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing on a Dell Latitude (13" inch screen) running Win7 and IE9.

Comment: 13 inch screens... such blasphemy.

Comment: @Ryathal tell me something I don't know :)  Obviously the moron in procurment doesn't actually use it or they would see how little vertical real estate there is.

Comment: @Ryathal Luckily, the compensated with nice 25" monitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fix is now on dev, will be in the next production build.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, but how often do you ship?

Comment: @GlennNelson we normally do production builds daily, after midnight EST.

Comment: @GlennNelson btw for today, we're pushing out a prod build very soon, in about 15mins or so.

Comment: It's fixed now. Thanks!